# Sort list of strings and give preference to string more closer to start index

Tags: javascript, string, sorting

Creating a web-component that shows results as you type. Currently I have list of string like:

```
[
  'Aaeaca Bi',
  'Aegaca Bd',
  'Biah gi',
  'dBciag ch',
  'Ghiad dl',
]
```

To search when the user type 'B', currently I'm getting results as:

```
'Aaeaca Bi',
'Aegaca Bd',
'Biah gi',
'dBciag ch'
```

but I want:

```
'Biah gi',
'dBciag ch',
'Aegaca Bd',
'Aaeaca Bi',
```

I want to get search results giving preference to result which is more closer to start index.

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: By what are you sorting the list? What have you tried? Have you thought about creating a new list each time a new character is entered and sorting it [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)?

Comment: You just need to sort your results by the index of 'B' in each of the result strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort by the difference in the `indexOf` of the string to find in the array item:

```js
const arr = [
  'Aaeaca Bi',
  'Aegaca Bd',
  'Biah gi',
  'dBciag ch',
  'Ghiad dl',
  'xxxx',
];
const strToFind = 'B';
const result = arr
  .filter(str => str.includes(strToFind))
  .sort((a, b) => a.indexOf(strToFind) - b.indexOf(strToFind))
console.log(result);
```

It *probably* doesn't matter in this situation (for a given piece of code, performance rarely does), but you could decrease the computational complexity to `O(n)` rather than `O(n log n)` by using counting sort rather than the built-in `.sort`.

If you want search to be case-insensitive, turn the initial array into one whose items contain both the lowercase version and the original version, then perform operations by checking the lowercase version, and map to the original version at the end:

```js
const arr = [
  'Aaeaca Bi',
  'Aegaca Bd',
  'Biah gi',
  'dBciag ch',
  'Ghiad dl',
  'xxxx',
  'aabaa'
];
const casedArr = arr.map(str => [str.toLowerCase(), str]);
const strToFind = 'B'.toLowerCase();
const result = casedArr
  .filter(([str]) => str.includes(strToFind))
  .sort((a, b) => a[0].indexOf(strToFind) - b[0].indexOf(strToFind))
  .map(([, origCasedStr]) => origCasedStr);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `filter` creates a new array. so no need of `slice`

Comment: Oops, you're right. I originally used `sort` first, so I made sure to `slice`, and then realized I needed to `filter` as well, but didn't remove the `slice`

Comment: @CertainPerformance would be good if you make it case insensitive since OP is talking about search.